# Characterisation of Limes superior

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $ (a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ a bounded sequence and $ a\in \mathbb{R} $. Then $$ \lim\sup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=a $$
> if and only if the following applies for all $ \varepsilon>0 $:
>
> i) $ a_n<a+\varepsilon $ for all but finitely $ n\in \mathbb{N} $
>
> ii) $ a_n>a-\varepsilon $ for infinitely $ n\in \mathbb{N} $.

Here is a proof which I cannot comprehend and I don't have an own idea how I could proof the upper statement:

**The proof**

> Let $ g_k:=\sup_{n\geq k} a_n $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N} $.
>
> Show ,,=>''. Let $ \varepsilon>0 $ arbitrary. Because of $ a=\lim\sup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}g_k $ there exists $ N_{\varepsilon}\in \mathbb{N} $ with $$ a-\varepsilon\leq g_k\leq a+\varepsilon $$
> for all $ k\geq N_{\varepsilon} $. Because of $ a_n\leq g_{N_{\varepsilon}} $ for all $ n\geq N_{\varepsilon} $ we get i). $ (g_k) $ is monotonous decreasing.

So far so good. Until here I undrstand everything. But for ii) I get stuck:

1.)

> Suppose ii) is wrong. Then $ a_n>a-\varepsilon $ is true for finitely $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ and so there exists an explicit $ N\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ a_n\leq a-\varepsilon $ for all $ n\geq N $.

Why??!!! This negation looks so weird to me especially the part
$ a_n\leq a-\varepsilon $ for all $ n\geq N $. I don't see any reason why there exists an explicit $ N\in \mathbb{N} $ with $ a_n\leq a-\varepsilon $ for all $ n\geq N $.

Infinitely $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ means for me that there is a set $ M\subseteq \mathbb{N} $ with $ |M|=\infty $ such that $ a_{n_M}>a-\varepsilon $ for all $ n_M\in M $. For example $ M $ could look like this $ M=\mathbb{N}\setminus{\{1,5,42,99\}} $. Now if I take the same $ N  $ from above: What does guarantee $ N > 1,5,42,99 $ such that $ a_n\leq a-\varepsilon $ for all $ n\geq N $?

2.)

> This implies $ g_k\leq a-\varepsilon $ for all $ k\geq N $ because $ a-\varepsilon $ is an upper bound and $ g_k $ a supremum. But then we get $$ a=\lim_{k\to \infty} g_k\leq a-\varepsilon $$ which is a contradiction because of $ \varepsilon>0 $ was given arbitrary.

If accept the part 1.) then I clearly understand 2.) and I understand the argumentation in part 2.).

3.)

> Show ,,<=''. Let $ \varepsilon>0 $ arbitrary. Then especially with ii) it follows $ g_k>a-\varepsilon $ for all $ k\in \mathbb{N}. $

Again: The same problem for me like in 1.). How do we know that?

4.)

> This shows $ \lim\limits_{k\to \infty}g_k\geq a $.
>
> Because of i) for all $ \varepsilon>0 $ there exists $ N_{\varepsilon}\in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $ n\geq N_{\varepsilon} $ it follows $ a_n<a+\varepsilon $ which implies $ g_k\leq a+\varepsilon $ for all $ k\geq N_{\varepsilon} $. With that get $ \lim\limits_{k\to \infty} g_k\leq a+\varepsilon $ and inclusion $ \lim\limits_{k\to \infty} g_k=a $.

Part 4.) is clear for me.

Comment: (For 1.) if (ii) is false then $a_n > a - \epsilon$ for at most finitely many $n$ (this is just directly the negation of (ii)). Suppose there is no $N$ such that $a_n \le a - \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Then for any $N$ we choose, there is always some $n \ge N$ where $a_n > a - \epsilon$, i.e., there are infinitely such $n$ such that $a_n > a - \epsilon$, which contradicts the assumption $a_n > a - \epsilon$ is only true for finitely many $n$.

Comment: From your comment on this part I think you might be getting a bit mixed up about the phrase 'explicit N': the point is that if you imagine listing out $1, 2, ..,$ you will get to some $N$ so that for $N+1, N+2, ...$ this holds. It doesn't mean there is some particular $N$ that this always holds. Indeed, for a sequence given the smallest such $N$ that this holds I could always add on 10 points at the beginning (or anywhere in the first $N$) so it doesn't hold for all $ n \ge N$. But now it just holds for all $n \ge N+10$, instead.

Comment: The point is that because we are dealing with a sequence that converges to some point the addition of finitely many points, wherever in the sequence, will not effect the eventual convergence: because we can always find some point later on where the points are always close to the limit enough to satisfy our $\epsilon$. This is just what it means for a sequence to converge.